# setfattr operation not supported

Tags: linux, ubuntu, linux-kernel

```
$ touch foobar
$ setfattr -n user.foo -v bar foobar
setfattr: foobar: Operation not supported
```

The file as all permission, same for folder. What could be the issue here? It's Ubuntu 9.10

This is in my fstab

```
/dev/sdb1 /var/log/apache_logs          reiserfs    user,noauto,rw,exec,suid,user_xattr
```

(I'm working somewhere in those dir but I've tried elsewhere too and it's the same)

Comment: You should install a newer version of Ubuntu.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't do that x)

Comment: Its possibly that the underlying file system does not support the xattr which is required for the `setfattr and getfattr` commands. 9.10 is quite old.

Comment: did you verify that your kernel is build with CONFIG_REISERFS_FS_XATTR=y ?   Do you have any kernel message on mounting your reiserfs filesystem ?

Comment: Came across this while getting the same problem but for a different reason. Don't forget to add a namespace identifier as `setfattr -n foo -v bar ./foobar.txt` gives you the same error. Namespaces (as of right now) are:  user, trusted, security and system noted [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_file_attributes#Linux).

Comment: does `attr -s` do anything?